# Parse datetime string in the format "Nov. 7, 2012, 9:02 p.m."

Tags: c#

How can I parse a date string in the format "Nov. 7, 2012, 9:02 p.m."

I think I'm close. Have tried:

```
        string line = "Nov. 7, 2012, 9:02 p.m.";
        string format = "MMM. dd, yyyy, hh:mm p.m."; ;
        DateTime result = DateTime.ParseExact(line, format, null);
```

Comment: instead of p.m., use "tt" in format

Answer (score 1):

This will work.

```
        string format = string.Format("{0:MMM. dd, yyyy, hh:mm tt}", DateTime.Now);
        Console.WriteLine(format);
```

This will print the result in your expected format ( Nov. 7, 2012, 9:02 PM)

Comment: Almost there. Prints "Nov. 07, 2012, 11:25 PM", so the "PM" should be "p.m." and the date (and probably hour) shouldn't be 0 justified. Maybe I should just do some string replacement on the p.m.

Comment: But what will happen when the time is 11:12 ? If  you need only a single digit hour, then use "h" instead of "hh"

Answer (score 0):

```
string format = "MMMM. dd, yyyy, hh:mm p.m.";
```

your taking the full month with 4 M's

Try

```
string format = "MMM. dd, yyyy, hh:mm p.m.";
```

to get the short month ie November -> Nov

Here's the reference guide: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use a single`h` instead of `hh`. Also , `t.'m'.` might match your a.m./p.m. depending on if it's case sensitive.